# Why continuity at countably many points can be extended

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

The expression in the picture is true for countably many points $1-\alpha$ of continuity of $F$ (a distribution function on the real line). I need help understanding the explanation (below the equation in the picture) of why the monotonicity of left and right hand side of the equation in $\alpha$ and the continuity of $1-\alpha$ implies this is true for all values of $\alpha$. I have no idea, thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove the following (more general) statement.

> Let $p=p(n,\alpha)$ be such that
>
> - $p(n,\alpha) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$ except $\alpha \in N$ where $N$ is a countable set
> - $f$ is continuous
> - $\alpha \mapsto p(n,\alpha)$ is non-increasing
>
> Then $p(n,\alpha) \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.

*Proof:* Fix $\alpha \in N$. Since $N$ is countable, we can find sequences $(\beta_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\gamma_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\beta_j \uparrow \alpha$, $\gamma_j \downarrow \alpha$ and $\gamma_j, \beta_j \notin N$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Because of the monotonicity, we have

$$p(n,\beta_j) \geq p(n,\alpha) \geq p(n,\gamma_j)$$

for all $j,n \in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $n \to \infty$, we find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} p(n,\beta_j) \geq \limsup_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} p(n,\gamma_j).$$

Since $\beta_j,\gamma_j \notin N$, we obtain

$$f(\beta_j) \geq  \limsup_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq f(\gamma_j)$$

for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Using the continuity of $f$, we conclude by letting $j \to \infty$

$$f(\alpha) \geq \limsup_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq \liminf_{n \to \infty} p(n,\alpha) \geq f(\alpha).$$

This finishes the proof.

Comment: :) thank you, the solution is clear

Comment: @monalisa You are welcome. if you find the answer helpful, you can upvote (/accept) it by clicking on the uparrow (/tick) next to it.